# How to load html file into article content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I download an extension from freefrontedit and upload it on my server to directory /accordeon.
When I point the browser to http://mysite/accordeon/index.html it works well.
But how could I load the index.html into article content?
I am using joomla template.

I try with `<iframe  src="http://mysite/accordeon/index.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>` but then the height is not same.

Is there other way to load accordeon/index.html into an article?

Comment: set the height to auto

Comment: not working and also accordeon is changing its height. I write down the html code from index.html into the article but its only partly working because the extension has also index.HAML file and my articles didn't recognize its script and show it as plain text

Comment: A working snippet would be good for testing here

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106489/is-loading-the-article-content-using-jquery-ajax-bad-for-seo This may help you.plz refer this

Comment: Nothing to help there... I wonder how this  custom extensions can be used in cms like joomla and wordpress without iframe your own content because iframe height is never the same as the source.  Pasting index.html code in article content works only when they dont have index.HAML file because article didn't understand HAML code and display it as plain text

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how this  custom extensions can be used in cms like joomla and wordpress without iframe your own content because iframe height is never the same as the source.  Pasting index.html code in article content works only when they dont have index.HAML file because neither article neither custom html module could understand HAML code and just display it as plain text